# Defered-loaded background image flickers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I keep all the javascript for my site in one huge file - my_scripts.js. On all pages, I defer the loading of this file (using an in-lined javascript). It is the last thing that loads.

Because for my HTML body I use a large background image, I thought it a good idea to also defer the loading of this image. From my body css class I deleted this part: `background-image: url('my_background.jpg');`

Then, as the first line of my my_scripts.js I added this: `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(my_background.jpg)";`

Now, the css needed to show the background image is added into my main style-sheet with javascript. Works, the large background loads after everything else has loaded.

But: when I navigate between pages, the background image flickers. It is loaded each time. What am I doing wrong? my_scripts.js should be in the browser's cache! Why the flicker?

EDIT: Still flickers if I preload the image with

```
if (document.images) {
img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "my_background.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image:url('my_background.jpg)";` instead of `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(my_background.jpg)";`, because, simply, your CSS rule worked with no flicker. Simple.

Comment: I need to add the background with JS. Because... too much and too boring for readers to explain..